# How to delete a record in django using cloud firestore?

Tags: django, google-cloud-firestore

**Error:**
[image: error img]

I'm trying to delete a record in my table but this is giving me an error

Error : Reverse for 'delete_Building' with arguments '('Ep7AzCd3rcUvDjvwhvL5',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

> ID is selected but template is not loading because of above error

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
          <!-- Simple Tables -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
             <a href="{% url 'building:registerBuilding'%}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle "></i> Add Building</a>
         </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table align-items-center table-flush" id="buildingList">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                  <tr>
                    <th>BUILDING NAME</th>
                    <th>POSTAL CODE</th>
                    <th>STREET</th>
                    <th>HOUSE NO.</th>
                    <th>TOWN</th>
                    <th>ADDITIONAL INFO</th>
                    <th colspan="2">ACTION</th>
                    
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
             {% for building in buildings %}     
           <tr>  
              <td>{{ building.building }}</td>  
              <td>{{ building.postalCode }}</td>  
              <td>{{ building.houseNo }}</td>
              <td>{{ building.street }}</td>
              <td>{{ building.town }}</td>  
              <td>{{ building.additionalInfo }}</td>
              <td><a href="{% url 'building:updateBuilding' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit"  ><i class="fa fa-pen"></i>Edit</a></td>
              <td><a href="{% url 'building:delete_Building' building.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs text-white" data-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</a></td>  
             </tr>  
            {% endfor %}
               
               
               
              
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!---Container Fluid-->
  </div>
```

**views.py:**

```
def delete_Building(request, id):
 docId = id;
 db.collection('Buildings').document(docId).delete();
 return redirect(reverse('building:buildingMag'))
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('delete/<str:id>/',views.delete_Building,name='delete_Building'),
```

Comment: why dont you try <str:id> instead of <int:id>

Comment: tried this now template is loading, but when i clicked on the delete button this error pops up                                                                                                                                                 image Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwQHT.png

Comment: i dont think i have enough knowledge about the way you are deleting the building instance. If i were you i would use ORM way that is : building = Collections.objects.get(id=doc_id)  and delete the building by : building.delete()

Comment: And in the above comment i am assuming Collections is the model which has every building objects and doc_id is the building instance id

Comment: I'm not using ORM, using firestore as a database so that's why unable to use ORM, and now i'm able to delete the records, only thing which is causing problem is the http response when i delete the record it redirect me to my login page, but not on the same page

Comment: That's because you asked it to redirect to the home page `return redirect("/")` in the `delete_building` view.

Comment: but when i add url of the same page it gives me an error of page not found

Comment: Did you hard code the url or use the `reverse()` function while redirecting ? In case you have hard coded the url, you could use [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) which should solve the issue.

Comment: no I haven't use reverse() function, but the term hard coded I didn't get it?

Comment: my code is written above, please check it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You have said that "i add url of the same page it gives me an error of page not found", I want to know what you have changed.

Comment: If you have the current page from which you are deleting registered in the urlpatterns with a name you can use it in the `reverse` function. Refer its docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Comment: Sorry i haven't updated the code earlier, please check now, views.py file

Comment: Now I get it, `EmployeeAdmin/buildingMag.html` is not a valid url. You could mitigate this by using `reverse()`..

Comment: like this reverse("EmployeeAdmin/buildingMag.html")?

Comment: No, `redirect(reverse('name parameter of the current current page which you have used in urlpatterns'))`

Comment: If this is confusing or if you have not registered the current page in urlpatterns, then you can simply use `return render(request, "EmployeeAdmin/buildingMag.html")`. Render docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) and example usage [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render)

Comment: def delete_Building(request, id):
     docId = id;
     db.collection('Buildings').document(docId).delete();
     return redirect(reverse('delete/'))    like this?

Comment: tried this return render(request, "EmployeeAdmin/buildingMag.html") but this redirects to the same page but no existing records are been displayed.See the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/nofIR.png

Comment: @Kishore i didn't get this meaning "name parameter of the current page which you have used in urlpatterns"?                                                                                                        can you check my urls.py file above?

Comment: may be you can use this at the end of the  delete view return redirect("name parameter of the current page ")

Comment: name parameter is the [ name="buildings_page"  ] inside the urls.py

Comment: Yes, it worked!!! , thank you so much, I have also updated the views.py file now :)

Comment: @SaadHassan Glad to help :)